# How to access a point in postgis database from Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, point

I am trying to get points (latitude longitude coordinates) from my database using django / postgis, but I run into this error that I can't figure:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type point to bytea
LINE 1: ...lon_id", "lat_lon"."house_id", "lat_lon"."lat_lon"::bytea FR...
```

My database looks like this:

[image: lat lon database]

And I set up my model (models.py) like this:

```
class LatLon(models.Model):
    lat_lon_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    house = models.ForeignKey(Houses, models.DO_NOTHING)
    lat_lon = models.PointField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'lat_lon'
    
    @property
    def lat_lng(self):
        return(list(getattr(self.lat_lon, 'coords', []))[::-1])
```

and make a listview (views.py):

```
class LatlonList(ListView):
    queryset = LatLon.objects.filter(lat_lon__isnull=False)
```

Finally my urlpatterns look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home"),
    path("hello/<name>", views.hello_there, name="hello_there"),
    path("about/", views.about, name="about"),
    path("contact/", views.contact, name="contact"),
    path("log/", views.log_message, name="log"),
    path("test_page/", views.LatlonList.as_view(template_name = 'test_page.html'), name="test_page"),
    path('map/', views.EntryList.as_view()),
```

I guess from the error that Django tries to cast my points to bytea data type, but I clearly specify in the model that they are points (Pointfield).

I am new to django, so any responses/hints are appreciated!

Comment: You are using PostgreSQL's native geometry type `POINT` here; this is a fundamentally different type than the PostGIS `GEOMETRY/GEOGRAPHY` types (which probably are better researched on [GIS.SE]). Depending on your use case your options include 1.) pull coordinate values individually (e.g. as `FLOAT`s); 2.) cast to PostGIS types (e.g. `lat_lon::GEOMETRY`; coordinate order matters: PostGIS assumes LonLat/XY) and pull a GeoJSON object; 3.) cast to PostGIS types and use GeoDjango to extract and decode WKB or 3.5) export as WKT

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help with showing me where the error was. I figured out the solution using your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution thanks to geozlot's comment.

I choose to add a geometry column to the database with the sql statement:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('lat_lon', 'lat_lon', 4326, 'POINT', 2, true)
```

Next, I can write PostGIS' geometry points to this column using;

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s), 4326))
```

where %s are placeholders for the longtitude and latitude.